# Red Hat 7 KickStarter

Tags: rhel, kickstart

I've made my own KickStarter with the official KickStarter generator from RedHat. But now I can't find out how I can run it. It is a `.dms` file.

Answer (score 0):

Open it up in `Notepad++` or another text editor for example, it's just a generated text file. You can change the name of the file to something more sensible like `kickstart.cfg`

[For info on doing a kickstart installation, hit up Red Hat's guides.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-kickstart-installations.html)